# Constructor does not exist

Tags: c++

I am attempting to implement a circular buffer. So now I am testing some code.

**raw_buffer.h**

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::min

#ifndef RAWBUFFER_H
#define RAWBUFFER_H

class CircularBuffer
{
public:
    CircularBuffer(size_t capacity);
    ~CircularBuffer();

    size_t size() const { return size_; }
    size_t capacity() const { return capacity_; }
    // Return number of bytes written.
    size_t write(const char *data, size_t bytes);
    // Return number of bytes read.
    size_t read(char *data, size_t bytes);

private:
    size_t beg_index_, end_index_, size_, capacity_;
    char *data_;
};

extern CircularBuffer MyCircularBuffer;

#endif
```

**main_raw.cpp**

```
#include "raw_buffer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   

using namespace std;

    int main() {
        const char *data_test1 = "AAAA";
        const char *data_test2 = "BBBB";
        const char *data_test3 = "CCCC";

        CircularBuffer Buffer;//<---error

        return 0;
    }
```

The line `CircularBuffer Buffer;` is giving me the error: "no default constructor exists for class "CircularBuffer".

Comment: What is confusing about this? Your declaration and use are completely different. Simply don't do that.

Comment: In this example how can I use this? I am trying to understand. Something like this? `CircularBuffer(12).write(data_teste1,4)`

Comment: You're the one who wrote the class. How come you don't know how to use it? That makes no sense.

Comment: No, I am trying some samples to understand the implementation. "testing some code"

Comment: Where did the code come from?

Comment: [link](http://www.asawicki.info/news_1468_circular_buffer_of_raw_binary_data_in_c.html)

Comment: That implementation has terrible bugs. You should learn C++ from [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), not from random "tuts" on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you defined this parameterized constructor, you disabled the compiler generated default constructor

```
CircularBuffer(size_t capacity);
```

You can add the following to get the default constructor back (note that the `default` keyword is new as of C++11)

```
CircularBuffer() = default;
```

Though you should make sure that your class is instantiated in a valid state. If default initialized values do not fit the bill, then you should manually define the default constructor to initialize your member variables to a valid state.

If you intended to call your parameterized constructor, then you need to pass the argument that you declared. E.g.

```
CircularBuffer buffer{10};   // constructed with a capacity of 10
```

Comment: It's unlikely a defaulted default ctor is the right solution here. You'd leave `capacity_` uninitialised... Are you sure this is good advice?

Comment: That is a good point, but I cannot answer that for the OP. They should either not use the default constructor if it doesn't make sense for this class, or use the compiler generated default, or define a default constructor that *does* leave the class in a valid state. Which they choose is up to them.

Comment: In general I agree but it is as least clear that leaving a member uninitialised after construction is a bad idea, which is unavoidable with your suggestion of `= default`.

Answer (score 3):

As @CoryKramer answered you didn t get a default constructor. If you want to change it you can also do this:

```
CircularBuffer(size_t capacity = 0);
```

by default if no capacity is send it will be are 0.